# Programmatically displaying a WebView with a TextView below it

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, textview

The following XML implementation seems to work fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/chatView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, the following Java implementation doesn't (there's a tiny space at the bottom after the `WebView`, but the `TextView` isn't visible.)

```
Context mContext = getActivity();

LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(mContext);
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

WebView web (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f));
web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

TextView text = new TextView(mContext);
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

view.addView(web);
view.addView(text);
```

Example:

[image: <code>TextView</code> should be where the back space at the bottom is, but taller of course.]

`TextView` should be where the black space at the bottom is, but taller of course. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to make the `WebView` resize around the `TextView` (I'm assuming this is what you want since you have the `android:weight` property), make sure that you set the height to "`0dp`" instead of "`fill_parent`". Otherwise, the `WebView` WILL fill the parent and your `TextView` won't be displayed.

In addition, since the `TextView`'s height is set to "`wrap_content`," you actually need content there if you want  to see it. See if it shows up once you set the text.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the quick response. I also meant to use EditText instead of TextView, heh. It's always some dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to set some text on TextView "text"

Similar like this `text.setText("This is text ")`